# Rsync hard-links when modification times are different

Tags: mac-osx, rsync

I have a large remote directory `A` and local directory `B` that are nearly identical in content, though many of the modification times may have changed by copying files etc.  I want to create a local directory `C` with identical content to `A`, hard-linking to files in `B` whenever the content is the same.  I don't care about getting the modification times the same.

Is this possible with `rsync`?

For a test case, I have the following local setup (I assume the behavior won't change when `A` is on a remote server):

```
[Compputer:/tmp] % cat A/a B/a
foo
foo

[Compputer:/tmp] % rsync -rIv --link-dest=$PWD/B/ /tmp/A/ /tmp/C  
building file list ... done
created directory /tmp/C
./
a
b

sent 169 bytes  received 71 bytes  480.00 bytes/sec
total size is 8  speedup is 0.03

[Compputer:/tmp] % ls -lT A B C
A:
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 ken  wheel  4 May 28 00:01:15 2016 a
-rw-r--r--  1 ken  wheel  4 May 28 00:01:22 2016 b

B:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 ken  wheel  4 May 28 00:01:34 2016 a

C:
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 ken  wheel  4 May 28 20:46:31 2016 a
-rw-r--r--  1 ken  wheel  4 May 28 20:46:31 2016 b
```

Notice that `a` isn't hardlinked.

Comment: Not sure whether this belongs on Stack Overflow or Super User better.  By subject matter I'd think so, but there seem to be more `rsync` questions on Server Fault than the other sites.  Please propose a move if appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: the `-c` switch requests that a checksum be compared for every file.  That ignores the last-modified dates, and `rsync` (usually) detects identical files better (at the expense of reading every file in full, but still not needing to transfer over the network).

```
[Compputer:/tmp] % rsync -rcv --link-dest=$PWD/B/ A/ C
building file list ... done
created directory C
./
b

sent 150 bytes  received 48 bytes  396.00 bytes/sec
total size is 8  speedup is 0.04
[Compputer:/tmp] % ls -l A B C
A:
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 ken  wheel  4 May 28 00:01 a
-rw-r--r--  1 ken  wheel  4 May 28 00:01 b

B:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  2 ken  wheel  4 May 28 00:01 a

C:
total 16
-rw-r--r--  2 ken  wheel  4 May 28 00:01 a
-rw-r--r--  1 ken  wheel  4 May 30 21:33 b
```

The `2` before the `a` files in `B/` and `C/` indicates that they are hard linked.